# While making a multi language website getting null array result while fetching the route name

Tags: laravel

```
<ul class="language" >        
<li><a href='{{route(Route::currentRouteName(),'en')}} '> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{{ __('English') }}</button></li></a>
<li><a href="{{route(Route::currentRouteName(),'ne')}}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{{ __('Nepali') }}</button></li></a>
</ul>
```

I was trying to fetch the current route bbut it provides me an error by saying Route[] not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
request()->route()->getName();
```